# value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've read about this issue in other SO posts and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. In principle, adding these two lines:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

should have done the trick but the error persists

This my build.sbt:

```
name := "PickACustomer"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "2.0.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0")
```

and my scala code is:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._


    object Foo{

    def reshuffle_rdd(rawText: RDD[String]): RDD[Map[String, (Vector[(Double, Double, String)], Map[String, Double])]]  = {...}

    def do_prediction(shuffled:RDD[Map[String, (Vector[(Double, Double, String)], Map[String, Double])]], prediction:(Vector[(Double, Double, String)] => Map[String, Double]) ) : RDD[Map[String, Double]] = {...}

    def get_match_rate_from_results(results : RDD[Map[String, Double]]) : Map[String, Double]  = {...}


    def retrieve_duid(element: Map[String,(Vector[(Double, Double, String)], Map[String,Double])]): Double = {...}




    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
        if (!conf.getOption("spark.master").isDefined) conf.setMaster("local")

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        //This should do the trick
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        val PATH_FILE = "/mnt/fast_export_file_clean.csv"
        val rawText = sc.textFile(PATH_FILE)
        val shuffled = reshuffle_rdd(rawText)

        // PREDICT AS A FUNCTION OF THE LAST SEEN UID
        val results = do_prediction(shuffled.filter(x => retrieve_duid(x) > 1) , predict_as_last_uid)
        results.cache()

        case class Summary(ismatch: Double, t_to_last:Double, nflips:Double,d_uid: Double, truth:Double, guess:Double)

        val summary = results.map(x => Summary(x("match"), x("t_to_last"), x("nflips"), x("d_uid"), x("truth"), x("guess")))


        //PROBLEMATIC LINE
        val sum_df = summary.toDF()

    }
    }
```

I always get:

> value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Summary]

Bit lost now. Any ideas?

Comment: can you at least type your values and give us the definition of the used methods ?

Comment: try to define your 'case class Summary' outside the main

Comment: @eliasah, sorry, kind of new to scala, didn't realise that would help. See edit.

Comment: case classes inside other objects might still pose a problem with serialization.

Comment: actually you can summarize your code with the following inside of the main : val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val summary: RDD[Summary] = ???
    case class Summary(ismatch: Double, t_to_last: Double, nflips: Double, d_uid: Double, truth: Double, guess: Double)
    val sum_df = summary.toDF()

Comment: unfortunately, i can't reproduce the error....

Comment: would you want me to show the whole code? it's not a lot but I thought that would make the issue basically unreadble

Comment: no need for the whole code. sometimes defining values to use without actually applying a value to them is enough but in that case typing is important. Just try to run `sbt update`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Putting the definition summary out of the main function did the trick. I wonder what that manifested itself with that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your case class outside of `main`:

```
object Foo {

  case class Summary(ismatch: Double, t_to_last:Double, nflips:Double,d_uid: Double, truth:Double, guess:Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    ...
  }

}
```

Something about the scoping of it is preventing Spark from being able to handle the automatic derivation of the schema for `Summary`. FYI I actually got a different error from `sbt`:

> No TypeTag available for Summary

Comment: Just in case this helps someone -  moving the class outside the object caused a similar problem. The class has to be inside foo and outside main

Answer (score 0):

great. save my life

Move your case class outside of main:

```
object Foo {

    case class Summary(ismatch: Double, t_to_last:Double, nflips:Double,d_uid: Double, truth:Double, guess:Double)

    def main(args: Array[String]){
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your case class outside of the function body. Then use 
`import spark.implicits._`.