# spark sbt error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[DataRow]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some spark scala code that works without an issue in spark-shell.

The core of this issue lies on these few lines. I want to add an additional line to a dataframe:

```scala
object SparkPipeline {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = (SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("SparkPipeline")
        .getOrCreate()
        )

    df = (spark
        .read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
        .load(DATA_PATH)
        )

    case class DataRow(field1: String, field2: String)
    val row_df = Seq(DataRow("FOO", "BAR")).toDF()  // THIS FAILS
    val df_augmented = df.union(row_df)
    //
    // Additional code here
    //
  }
}
```

However, when I use sbt to package it as a jar, sbt fails with the following error :

```
value toDF is not a member of Seq[DataRow]
```

I tried as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055774/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd) to do:

```scala
val spark = (SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("TrainSimpleRF")
    .getOrCreate()
    )

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Which does not fix the issue. Also tried importing `spark.implicits_` to no avail. I have all the code in the main method. I think that might matters( as per some answers in cloudera forums) but haven't managed to make it work regardless of how I structure the code.

How do I make it work? Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: Did you try moving your case class outside of the main method like the accepted answer says to do in the question that you linked?

Comment: I think it is the closing parenthesis just before toDF `row_df = Seq(DataRow("FOO", "BAR")).toDF()`

Comment: @Jeremy I did, yes. However I am no scala expert and might not have done it properly. How would you do it if I may ask?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala/Spark App with "No TypeTag available" Error in "def main" style App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143756/scala-spark-app-with-no-typetag-available-error-in-def-main-style-app)

Comment: Just a quick comment, had a similar error but the case class was defined outside any object however I forgot to do `import sqlContext.implicits._` before the call to `toDF`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, as stated in [this post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-Scala-Error-value-toDF-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark/m-p/29994#M973), I just had to move the class definition outside the main function like:

```scala
// Define the class DataRow prior to the object with the main method
case class DataRow(field1: String, field2: String)

object SparkPipeline {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = (SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("SparkPipeline")
        .getOrCreate()
        )

    df = (spark
        .read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
        .load(DATA_PATH)
        )


    val row_df = Seq(DataRow("FOO", "BAR")).toDF()  // THIS FAILS
    val df_augmented = df.union(row_df)
    //
    // Additional code here
    //
  }
}
```

It took me a while to process that answer, but its there.